# Rails 6 - Values from view not reaching the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

=> Rails 6.0.3

Dates not passing from view/form to controller.

**What works**

1. In the view, the date fields are pre-populated with the default values from  */models/case_search.rb* - *def initialize(params)*
2. A list of cases is pulled from the DB

   > ```sql
   > SELECT "cases".*
   > FROM "cases"
   > WHERE (closed_date BETWEEN '2020-05-23' AND '2020-05-25')
   > ```

**What fails**

1. When I change the dates in the form fields, the URL changes to:

   > http://localhost:3000/teams/5?Date+from=2020-05-10&Date+to=2020-05-15&commit=List

   But the list of cases remains unchanged:

   > ```sql
   > SELECT "cases".*
   > FROM "cases"
   > WHERE (closed_date BETWEEN '2020-05-23' AND '2020-05-25')
   > ```

Somehow the `@search` variable reaches the controller empty and it always defaults to the values set in */models/case_search.rb* - *def initialize(params)* - *def parsed_date(date_string, default)*.

Can someone spot where the problem is?

I have the following form in `/teams/show.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_tag team_path, method: "get" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'Date from', @search.date_from %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'Date to', @search.date_to %>
    <%= submit_tag 'List', class: 'btn btn-dark' %>
<% end %>
```

The controller `teams_controller.rb` file has:

```
def show
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])
    @team_owner = User.find(@team.owner)
    @search = CaseSearch.new(params[:search])
    @cases = @search.scope
end
```

I have created a new model file `/models/case_search.rb` to handle the search:

```
class CaseSearch
attr_reader :date_from, :date_to

def initialize(params)
    params ||= {}
    @date_from = parsed_date(params[:date_from], 2.days.ago.to_date.to_s)
    @date_to = parsed_date(params[:date_to], Date.today.to_s)
end

def scope
    Case.where('closed_date BETWEEN ? AND ?', @date_from, @date_to)
end

private
    def parsed_date(date_string, default)
        Date.parse(date_string)
     rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
        default
    end
end
```

Comment: If I change the file /models/case_search.rb to this:

`def initialize(params)
  params ||= {}
  @date_from = Date.parse(params[:date_from])
  @date_to = Date.parse(params[:date_to])
 end`

I get the following error:
TypeError in TeamsController#show
no implicit conversion of nil into String
@date_from = Date.parse(params[:date_from])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the following lines:

In the controller:

> ```
> @search = CaseSearch.new(params[:search])
> ```

In case_search you access `params[:date_from]` and `params[:date_to]`.

In the view:

> ```
> <%= text_field_tag 'Date from', @search.date_from %>
> <%= text_field_tag 'Date to', @search.date_to %>
> ```

From the above I assume you are expecting `params` to have the structure:

```
{search: {date_from: 'value', date_to: 'value'}}
```

This isn't reflected in the form.

The line `text_field_tag 'Date from'` will make the value available under `params['Date from']` in the controller, which isn't what you want. Instead change the view to:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'search[date_from]', @search.date_from %>
<%= text_field_tag 'search[date_to]', @search.date_to %>
```

So it matches the structure you're expecting.

The guide [Action Controller Overview](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters) has a section specifically about this:

> ### [4.1 Hash and Array Parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters)
>
> The `params` hash is not limited to one-dimensional keys and values.
>   It can contain nested arrays and hashes. To send an array of values,
>   append an empty pair of square brackets "[]" to the key name:
>
> ```
> GET /clients?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3
> ```
>
> > The actual URL in this example will be encoded as "/clients?ids%5b%5d=1&ids%5b%5d=2&ids%5b%5d=3" as the "[" and "]"
> >     characters are not allowed in URLs. Most of the time you don't have to
> >      worry about this because the browser will encode it for you, and Rails
> >     will decode it automatically, but if you ever find yourself having to
> >     send those requests to the server manually you should keep this in
> >     mind.
>
> The value of `params[:ids]` will now be `["1", "2", "3"]`. Note that
>   parameter values are always strings; Rails makes no attempt to guess
>   or cast the type.
>
> > Values such as `[nil]` or `[nil, nil, ...]` in `params` are
> >     replaced with `[]` for security reasons by default. See
> >     [Security Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#unsafe-query-generation) for more information.
>
> To send a hash, you include the key name inside the brackets:
>
> ```
> <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/clients" method="post">
>   <input type="text" name="client[name]" value="Acme" />
>   <input type="text" name="client[phone]" value="12345" />
>   <input type="text" name="client[address][postcode]" value="12345" />
>   <input type="text" name="client[address][city]" value="Carrot City" />
> </form>
> ```
>
> When this form is submitted, the value of `params[:client]` will be `{ "name" => "Acme", "phone" => "12345", "address" => { "postcode" => "12345", "city" => "Carrot City" } }`. Note the nested hash in
>   `params[:client][:address]`.
>
> The `params` object acts like a Hash, but lets you use symbols and
>   strings interchangeably as keys.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `text_field_tag` has a different key to what you are trying to retrieve. Try changing to:

```
<%= text_field_tag :date_from, @search.date_from %>
<%= text_field_tag :date_to, @search.date_to %>
```

Comment: Didn't change the behavior, the variable @search remains unchanged: 

http://localhost:3000/teams/5?date_from=2020-05-20&date_to=2020-05-25&commit=List

`<%= debug @search %>
--- !ruby/object:CaseSearch
date_from: '2020-05-23'
date_to: '2020-05-25'`

Comment: What is the output of your `params[:search]`?